# Unable to solve the limit question - deducing the constants in a function based on given facts.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I was looking for calculus practice problems, and found the following [online resource](https://web.pdx.edu/%7Eerdman/CALCULUS/CALCULUS_pdf.pdf). I was unable to solve the following problem:

[image: Problem Screenshot]

The instructor asks us to use the facts about the function $g$ given in the problem to solve the question. I deduced that $c=0$ and $d=-e$. My question is as follows:

1. The instructor mentions using one of the hints to solve for $a$. I am unsure how to do so. The hint mentions that $g(x)\geq 0$ for $x\in[0,1)$ and negative elsewhere. How can I utilize this to find the value for $a$?
2. The instructor mentions using the formula $\sin(A+B)$ to evaluate the limit mentioned in the question. I do not understand how to apply this formula.

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). In particular, make your question self-contained (no external links) and keep it focused to one question.

Comment: I get the function as $g(x)=-\frac{3x}{x-1}$, also you must see the link posted above by  @JoseAvilez to get good answers

Comment: @LalitTolani could you please post your answer along with the steps ? It would be really helpful.